# Teres minor rehab isolation exercises

Tags: rehabilitation, isolation, rotator-cuff

I've determined that tightness/weakness in my teres minor is at least partially repsonsible for the clicking in my shoulder when I rotate, apparently in its function as an antagonist.

I have thera-bands, medicine balls, dumbbells and kettlebells I can use for the exercises.

What are exercises that specifically target the teres minor?

Answer (score 3):

The teres minor muscle is part of the rotator cuff and it externally (laterally) rotates the shoulder.  It does so in combination with the infraspinatus, so I'm not certain that you can fully isolate it.

**To Strengthen** the external rotators together, you can do so with:

- **Cables or resitance/thera-bands** in a [neutral position](http://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Infraspinatus/CBStandingExternalRotation.html) or in an [elevated position](http://youtu.be/BYPba3ms9io?t=2m)
- **Free weights** - [sidelying](http://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Infraspinatus/DBLyingExternalRotation.html)
- **Levers or weight machines** - in [neutral](http://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Infraspinatus/LVExternalRotation.html) or [elevated](http://exrx.net/WeightExercises/Infraspinatus/LVUprightExternalRotation.html)

Because you say you have shoulder symptoms, a small towel roll between your chest wall and your humerus will reduce shoulder joint stress when doing the above exercises in the neutral or sidelying position.

**Stretching** - When the teres minor is tight it limits shoulder internal rotation.  You can stretch the teres minor and infraspinatus with a [broomstick stretch](http://exrx.net/Stretches/Infraspinatus/Broomstick.html).  Or [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=luoiGpT4PJ8) gives some nice rotator cuff stretches with different ways to target the external rotators.  You can also release the muscles using a tennis ball or theracane to massage the muscle.

If you haven't already, getting a full evaluation by a physical therapist or physio would be helpful to check for other contributing factors and stabilization of the scapula.